# Android Glide click on item Gridview show image full screen

Tags: android, gridview, android-glide

I'm using Glide to download and display images in my gridview. When I click on a item in my gridview I want to display this image in another activity to get this image in full screen. But with Glide I don't know how I can get the image saved in the cache.

1. Save the image filename in a Database and call again the link to download the image full size with Glide ?
2. Or try to get the image in the cache but I don't know how to do that.

Could you help me ?

Answer (score 3):

try this code, it's working for me:

On your adapter:

```
            Glide.with(context)
                .load("photo_url")
                .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.ALL) //use this to cache
                .centerCrop()
                .crossFade()
                .into(yourImageView);
```

On your another Activity:

```
            Glide.with(AnotherActivity.this)
            .load("photo_url")
            .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.ALL) //use this to cache
            .crossFade()
            .into(yourImageView);
```

Use `.diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.ALL)` to cache & don't forget to make **image scaling same**. It will working.